# php ftp check if folder exists always return error creating folder

Tags: php, ftp

can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong in this code?

```
if($id != '') {
    if(is_dir("../public_html".$tem_pasta['path']."/pics/".$id)) {
        echo "pasta já existia";
        $destination_file = "../public_html".$tem_pasta['path']."/pics/".$id."/".$myFileName;
    } else {
        //pasta nao existia
        if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, "../public_html".$tem_pasta['path']."/pics/".$id)) {
            $destination_file = "../public_html".$tem_pasta['path']."/pics/".$id."/".$myFileName;
        //echo "pasta criada<br>";
        } else {
            echo "erro, não criou a pasta<br>";
        }
    }
} else {
    $destination_file = "../public_html".$tem_pasta['path']."/pics/".$myFileName;
}
```

it checks if I've a folder ($id) within my pics directory, and if not the script creates a new one.
works good, but if I try to upload another file to the previous created folder it does return an error, saying it didn't create the folder...

thanks

Comment: Was my awnser good? If so, please select it as correct awnser for people that are searching for this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`is_dir` works only on the local file-system. If you want to check if a ftp-directory already exists try this:

```
function ftp_is_dir($ftp, $dir)
{
    $pushd = ftp_pwd($ftp);

    if ($pushd !== false && @ftp_chdir($ftp, $dir))
    {
        ftp_chdir($ftp, $pushd);   
        return true;
    }

    return false;
} 

if($id != '') {
    if(ftp_is_dir($conn_id, "../public_html".$tem_pasta['path']."/pics/".$id)) {
    // and so on...
```

Comment: ok, thanks both, i'll check in 2 hours (not at office now) and let you know the result. thanks

Comment: perfect! thank you very much, this little function made my day :-)

Comment: quick update 5 years later >_<, As of PHP 5.0.0, this is_dir can also be used with some URL wrappers. ie `is_dir('ftp://user:password@example.com/path/to/check')`. Just so people are aware

Comment: Note that the above command will break when users have : or @ in this username or password

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you can use is_dir on a FTP resource, what you should do is check if the size of the dir/file is -1 with ftp_size.

Because I think what now happens is: you are trying to make the same folder again, and this is why a error occurs.

Edit:
Or check with [ftp_chdir](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-chdir.php)!

```
<?php 
function ftp_directory_exists($ftp, $dir) 
{ 
    // Get the current working directory 
    $origin = ftp_pwd($ftp); 

    // Attempt to change directory, suppress errors 
    if (@ftp_chdir($ftp, $dir)) 
    { 
        // If the directory exists, set back to origin 
        ftp_chdir($ftp, $origin);    
        return true; 
    } 

    // Directory does not exist 
    return false; 
} 
?>
```

Should work!

Comment: Thanks for reply, it does work, but I just can put one correct answer.

Comment: I know, i was first but thats ok :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ftp_nlist`](http://php.net/manual/function.ftp-nlist.php) and in_array

```
$ftp_files = @ftp_nlist($this->connection, $directory);

if ($ftp_files === false) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to list files. Check directory exists: ' . $directory);
}

if (!in_array($directory, $ftp_files)) {
    $ftp_mkdir = @ftp_mkdir($this->connection, $directory);

    if ($ftp_mkdir === false) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to create directory: ' . $directory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With PHP 8.0 (on AWS) the solution with @ftp_chdir() does not hide the error and causes the program to stop. The solution with ftp_nlist() doesn't give good results because it returns either false if the path doesn't exist or an element if the path is a file or a list if it's a directory but doesn't give the "." and ".." elements that would identify a directory.

The ftp_mlsd() function seemed more convenient: it returns a list, possibly empty, only if the path is a directory, false otherwise. But it doesn't work correctly on all servers!

Finally it is the ftp_rawlist() function which seems to be the most generalized because it launches a LIST command on the server and returns the result. If the path is a directory we have an array, possibly empty and we have the value false if it is not a directory.

```
$list = ftp_rawlist( $ftp_conn, $remote_path );
$is_dir = is_array( $list );
```