# know if a file exist through FTP in php

Tags: php, ftp

I'm asking how know if a file already exist in a FTP in PHP.

For example I upload a file like that :

```
$ftp = ftp_connect(...;
ftp_login($ftp,...);
ftp_put(...);
```

But I have error chen I copy a file that already exist (so I have to rename the newest file to upload it correctly :-) )

So how to do to know if there is already a file named as the one I upload?

Comment: `file_exists('ftp://username:password@host.com/path/to/file');`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a file exists on a remote server using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852767/how-can-i-check-if-a-file-exists-on-a-remote-server-using-php) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665254/php-ftp-check-if-folder-exists-always-return-error-creating-folder

Comment: Okay thanks @MikeB so I can't use the $ftp connexion I've already made? I would prefer but thanks :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you upload, use the [ftp_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-size.php) function to see if there is a file.
If it returns anything that is not -1, then the file exists.